# How do I create a Bash script that loops in folders to copy files whose names contain specific strings?

Tags: bash, loops, command-line, copy, filenames

I'd like to write a script loops through several sub-folders, and copies all files containing a certain string, but I'm new to Bash. Here is my attempt so far, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
for folder in Organised\ by\ Filetype/*
do
    for file in $folder
    do
        if [ "$file" == *"Understand the meaning"* ]
        then
            cp $file Topic/01/
        fi
    done
done
```

The parent folder contains two sub-folders, "Organised by Filetype" and "Topic", and is also the one where the script is located and executed from. The "Organised by Filetype" sub-folder has several sub-folders that contain the files to search and copy from. The "Topic" sub-folder contains the desired destination sub-folders.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I assume 'source' is used" - Is this your attempt, or copied from someone else?

Comment: Please provide more details ([ask]) and provide a [mcve].  "It doesn't seem to work" is not a question.  You should take the [tour].  For your question, research the `find` command with the `-name` option and `-exec` to do your `cp`.

Comment: @jeremysprofile The 'source' was actually the name of the folder in the brief online Command Line course I took; I assumed it was used to refer to whatever folder the script is in, but I now see it refers to a specific folder. Original post edited to reflect that.

Comment: @Nic3500 So when I say "doesn't seem to work" I mean that when executed from the command line, the script returns nothing. In other words it fails to copy all files containing the string "Understand the meaning" somewhere in their filename, which is the objective.

Thanks - I'll look up  those commands / options and read through the pages you've linked to!

Comment: You could put `echo` command throughout the script to see what it does.  Like in the `for` loops, echo the variable values for each loop.  You will see what it is doing.  Another option is to put `#!/bin/bash -x`.  That will show you everything it does.  Sometimes it is a bit too much, so `echo` commands is sometimes more usefull (IMHO).

Comment: @Nic3500 Success! I've used ' find -name "*meaning*" -exec cp {} ./Topic/01 \; ' and that's achieved the objective! Thanks again for the find + exec suggestion!

Comment: Nicely done, and quickly too!  `find` is quite powerful once you learn to use it.

Comment: word splitting unquoted variables like $folder is one reason why it can't work